# trigger change event on dynamic generated dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

For a project, I'm making an item selector and for each selected item u get 3 dropdowns with choices. the first dropdown gets the options for the second dropdown and when u select the second dropdown u will get the last choices. These dropdowns are generated using partial views in ASP.net core 2. which I'm getting using Jquery change function.

There will be more panels with 3 dropdowns so it has to find the specific panel We're working with.

Html Code:

```
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                    <div class="ValueProposition" id="ValueProposition">
                        <label for="sel1">Selecteer Value Proposition:</label>
                        <select class="form-control ValuePropositionSelect" id="ValuePropositionSelect">
                            <option value="" hidden>Selecteer Value Proposition:</option>
                            @foreach (var ValueProposition in Model.ValuePropositions)
                            {
                                <option value="@ValueProposition.IdValueProposition" id="@ValueProposition.Name">@ValueProposition.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                    <div class="Cloud" id="Clouds" style="display:none">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                    <div class="Platforms" id="Platforms" style="display:none">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Code for onchange:

```
    <script>
$("select.CloudSelect").on('change', function (event) {
    console.log("select.Cloudselect changed function called");
    $(event.target).parents('.panel').find('a.CloudName').html("Platform: " + $(event.target).find(":selected").html());

    $(event.target).parents().closest('div.col-4').find('.Platforms').slideUp();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPlatformForCloudValueProposition")',
        data: {
            idCloud: event.target.value,
            idValueProposition: $(event.target).parents('.panel').find('a.ValuePropositionId').html()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(event.target).closest('div.col-4').find('.Platforms').html(data);
            $(event.target).closest('div.col-4').find('.Platforms').slideDown();
            console.log($(event.target).parents('.panel').find(':selected').html());
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
});
```

When only one value is passed trought the controller to the view it is supposed to run the onchange event but only for the dropbox in that panel:

```
<select class="form-control CloudSelect" id="CloudSelect">
@if (Model.cloudValuePropositions.Count() == 1)
{
    <option value="@Model.cloudValuePropositions.First().IdCloud">@Model.cloudValuePropositions.First().IdCloudNavigation.Name </option>
    <script>
        $(event.target).parents('.panel').find("select.CloudSelect").trigger("change");
    </script>
}
```

sketch for clarity:
[Sketch for clarirty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUjJk.png)

Comment: You need to use event delegation for dynamically added items - `$(document).on('change', '"select.CloudSelect', function (event) {` (but replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists when the page is first rendered

Comment: Can u give me an example, please? I want to use the panel where the dropbox is in with the class: ".panel".

should I do it like this:  `$(".panel").on('change', 'select.CloudSelect',function (event)`